# How do I combine both the login and registration page in Rails 3 using Devise?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

So this is what my `devise/sessions/new.html.erb` looks like:

```
<div id="sign_in">

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
            <%= f.text_field :f_name, :value => "First Name", :class => "clearField curved" %><div class="error"></div><br />
            <%= f.text_field :l_name, :value => "Last Name", :class => "clearField curved" %><div class="error"></div><br />
            <%= f.text_field :username, :value => "Username", :class => "clearField curved" %><div class="error"></div><br />
            <%= f.password_field :password, :value => "Password", :class => "clearField curved" %><div class="error"></div><br />
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :value => "Password", :class => "clearField curved" %><div class="error"></div><br />
            <%= f.text_field :email, :value => "Email Address", :class => "clearField curved" %><div class="error"></div><br />

        <div id="login_buttons">
            <%= f.submit "Sign in", :id => "login", :value => "Submit", :class => "curved" %>
            <%= f.submit "Sign in", :id => "register", :value => "Register", :class => "curved" %>
            <%= f.submit "Send Reset Instructions", :id => "pass-reset", :value => "Send Reset Instructions", :class => "curved"%>
            <a href="#" id="forgot-pw">Forgot pass?</a>
        </div>

    <% end %>

</div>
```

The above only works for the login (because the `:url => session_path(resource_name)` and not `registration_path`).

What this page does now, is on pageload it hides every field except the username & password field (i.e. it defaults to the login page). Then when they press the 'Register' button, it fades in the others.

However, when you press submit that doesn't work - because the wrong form handler is managing it.

This is what my regular registration form looks like (which works, btw) at `devise\registrations\new.html.erb`:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <p><%= f.label :username %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :username %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :email %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></p>

  <p><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></p>
<% end %>

<%= render :partial => "devise/shared/links" %>
```

The applicable part of my routes file looks like this:

```
devise_for :users, :path_names => { :sign_up => "register", 
                                  :sign_in => "login", 
                                  :sign_out => "logout" }

devise_scope :user do
    get "login", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
    get "register", :to => "devise/registrations#new"
    get "logout",   :to => "devise/sessions#destroy"
```

So the behavior I want is as follows:

The user goes to login, they see only two form fields (username + password). They press enter it logs them in.

If they press 'Register', without doing a pageload, I would like the right form (with the additional form fields required: first name, last name, etc.) to appear and when they press enter it does the registration. I would also like the URL to change from `myapp.com/login` to `myapp.com/register` - without a page load. If they pressed 'Sign In' without filling out the form, it should take them back to the login page (`myapp.com/login`) with only the two fields (username + pass) showing.

That way when I link directly to `myapp.com/register` it goes directly to that one page with the correct form fields and it functions properly.

Basically functionality similar to the way github now manages browsing through a repo with no page refreshes (but the URL changes).

Suggestions?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem ?

Comment: I didn't actually. I just broke them out into two separate pages. However, nelsonenzo's response below looks interesting. I haven't tried it, but if you do and say that it works I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

To combine user registration with user login on the same page, I did the following:
1) Copy all the code from views/sessions/new INTO view/registrations/new
2) Modify the submit button id/js namespace:

```
<%= f.submit 'submit_button', :style => "display: none", :id => "submitSignInForm" %><br>
<a class="button" href="javascript:document.getElementById('submitSignInForm').click();"> Sign in </a>"
```

3) Override the Devise Session Controller new method with a redirect.
create controllers/sessions_controller.rb and insert the following code.  Note the controller class inherits from Registrations, not Sessions!

```
class SessionsController < Devise::RegistrationsController  
  def new
    redirect_to new_user_registration_path
  end
end
```

*I should note, this worked in rails 2.3.5, but I think it will work in 3.0 the same.